# Retrieving an RxJS Observable of a nested Firestore query in AngularFire

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm trying to convert my Observable of an Object with `DocumentReference`s to an Observable of my entire Object.

My Firestore query returns an Observable of `QuestDocument`, which looks as follows (stripped of primitive types):

```
export interface QuestDocument {
    ...
    owner: DocumentReference<User>;
    ...
    collaborators?: DocumentReference<User>[];
    categories?: DocumentReference<Category>[];
}
```

Within my converter, I can call my other Firestore services to retrieve the values of the `DocumentReference`s to `User` and `Category` (flat structures, so no problems here).

My goal is to create an Observable of type `Quest`, but my nested Observables are not being resolved correctly.

```
export interface Quest {
  ...
  owner: User;
  ...
  collaborators?: User[];
  categories?: Category[];
}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
doc$(docId: string): Observable<Quest> {
  return this.doc(docId).valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(questDoc => {
      const owner$ = this.userService.doc$(questDoc.owner.id);
      const collaborators$ = forkJoin(questDoc.collaborators.map(
        (userRef: DocumentReference) => {
          return this.userService.doc$(userRef.id)
        }
      ));
      const categories$ = forkJoin(questDoc.categories.map(
        (categoryRef: DocumentReference) => this.categoryService.doc$(categoryRef.id)
      ));
      const joined = forkJoin({
        owner: owner$,
        collaborators: collaborators$,
        categories: categories$
      });
      joined.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
      return joined.pipe(
        map(value => {
          return Object.defineProperties(questDoc, {
            qid: { value: docId },
            owner: { value: value.owner },
            collaborators: { value: value.collaborators },
            categories: { value: value.categories }
          }) as Quest;
        })
      )
    })
  );
}
```

All the typings match up and I should receive an `Observable<Quest>`, but when I try to print the value it returns `undefined` and the second `.pipe()` is never reached.

Comment: `forkJoin` will only emit once all of the source observables have emitted and completed.  Do calls to `categoryService.doc$()` and `userService.doc$()` return observables that complete?  If not, you could add `.pipe(first())` to each of your 3 sources inside your `joined` forkJoin.

Comment: I'm not sure as to what *completion* means in terms of an Observable, as I'm still new to these concepts. The `.doc$()` calls of both services return Observables of the respective document-like types (see `QuestDocument`), mapped to the realized types (only added the document's ID onto the `Category` and `User`). The underlying functions that retrieve the document-like types are extensions of AngularFire's Firestore SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `forkJoin` operator correctly.

An observable that is complete will no longer emits data. Take it like a closed pipe.
`ForkJoin` will wait that all steams are completed (closed) before emitting one single data.

If you're fetching your data using `this.afs.collection(...).doc(...).valueChanges()`, these observables stay active. They will emit each time the data is updated in firestore.

To complete them, use a `take(1)` or `first()` (they will emit once then complete), or use `combineLatest()` to combine active streams and keep your data updated in real time (don't forget to unsubscribe onDestroy to prevent any memory leak).

Here's an example with completed streams:

```
doc$(docId: string): Observable<Quest> {
  return this.doc(docId).valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(questDoc => {
      // observable will emit then complete thanks to the "take(1)"
      const owner$ = this.userService.doc$(questDoc.owner.id).pipe(take(1));
      const collaborators$ = forkJoin(questDoc.collaborators.map(
        (userRef: DocumentReference) => {
          // same thing here 
          return this.userService.doc$(userRef.id).pipe(take(1))
        }
      ));
      const categories$ = forkJoin(questDoc.categories.map(
         // and here
        (categoryRef: DocumentReference) => this.categoryService.doc$(categoryRef.id).pipe(take(1))
      ));
      const joined = forkJoin({
        owner: owner$,
        collaborators: collaborators$,
        categories: categories$
      });
      // joined.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
      return joined.pipe(
        // NEVER subscribe within a pipe, use a tap operator for side effects
        tap(data => console.log(data)),
        map(value => {
          return Object.defineProperties(questDoc, {
            qid: { value: docId },
            owner: { value: value.owner },
            collaborators: { value: value.collaborators },
            categories: { value: value.categories }
          }) as Quest;
        })
      )
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was stuck on this problem for quite some time and never really thought about completion / the underlying Observables still being active. Also thanks for the pointer to the possibility of live updates (`combineLatest()`), as that was what I would try next :)